# How could SBT choose highest version amongst dependencies?

Tags: sbt

This is a question about versioning and workflow.

I have multiple projects

**projectA/build.sbt**

```
version := "1.0.0"
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.example" % "projectB" % "1.0.0",
  "com.example" % "util" % "1.0.0"
)
```

**projectB/build.sbt**

```
version := "1.0.0"
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.example" % "util" % "1.0.0"
)
```

**util/build.sbt**

```
version := "1.0.0"
```

------------------------ **DEVELOPMENT** ------------------------

I added a method in `util`.

**util/build.sbt**

```
version := "2.0.0"
```

This added functionality is great, so I use it to optimize `projectB`.

**projectB/build.sbt**

```
version := "1.1.0"
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.example" % "util" % "2.0.0"
)
```

------------------------ **DEVELOPMENT** ------------------------

I want `projectA` to be faster, so I pull in `projectB`.

**projectA/build.sbt**

```
version := "1.1.0"
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.example" % "projectB" % "1.1.0",
  "com.example" % "util" % "1.0.0"
)
```

------------------------ **PROBLEM** ------------------------

Now, `projectA` requires `util` version `1.0.0`, but `project B` requires `util` version `2.0.0`.

I can update `projectA` to use the new version of `util`. The issue is that the number of projects and dependencies I need to update can be be very large, and the chain of dependencies can be very long. (Imagine `projectZ` which depends on `projectA` and `util`.)

*Is there a way that I can have my project dependencies have a minimum version?*

For example, if `projectA` needs `util` version `1.0.0` and `projectB` needs `util` version `2.0.0`, `projectA` will wind up using the `2.0.0` version.

*If so, what would happen in this case if there were version `3.0.0` of `util` available? Would `projectA` wind up using `2.0.0`, or `3.0.0`?*

For me, it would be ideal if I could have a project use the greatest version, from among its own dependencies and (recursively) its dependents' dependencies, but no higher than that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> For me, it would be ideal if I could have a project use the greatest
>   version, from among its own dependencies and (recursively) its
>   dependents' dependencies, but no higher than that.

From the Sbt documentation http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Detailed-Topics/Library-Management.html#conflict-management :

> The conflict manager decides what to do when dependency resolution
>   brings in different versions of the same library. By default, the
>   latest revision is selected.

This is already the default behavior.

The same documentation explains how to force version, specify minimum version, etc.

Comment: Oh wonderful! And thanks for the link. I was used to Maven, which I believe takes the version specified by the closest dependency. This behavior is much better.