# sbt: how to write a MergeStrategy to choose a specific library version

Tags: merge, duplicates, sbt

Here is the attempt to exclude the javax.servlet classes:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
 ..
  ("org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.10" % sparkVersion  \
  % "compile->default"  withSources()).exclude("org.mortbay.jetty", "servlet-api"),
```

Here is my attempt at a MergeStrategy:

```
mergeStrategy in assembly <<= (mergeStrategy in assembly) { (old) => {
 ..
    case PathList("javax", "servlet", xs @ _*)         => MergeStrategy.singleOrError
   ..
```

Following shows that multiple copies of the javax.servlet classes are being loaded:

> [error] (*:assembly) singleOrError: found multiple files for same
>   target path: [error]
>   C:\Users\s80035683.ivy2\cache\org.mortbay.jetty\servlet-api-2.5\jars\servlet-api-2.5-6.1.14.jar:javax/servlet/Filter.class
>   [error]
>   C:\Users\s80035683.ivy2\cache\javax.servlet\servlet-api\jars\servlet-api-2.5.jar:javax/servlet/Filter.class
>   [error]
>   C:\Users\s80035683.ivy2\cache\org.eclipse.jetty.orbit\javax.servlet\orbits\javax.servlet-3.0.0.v201112011016.jar:javax/servlet/Filter.class
>   [error]
>   C:\Users\s80035683.ivy2\cache\org.mortbay.jetty\servlet-api\jars\servlet-api-2.5-20110124.jar:javax/servlet/Filter.class

Note: this is not a DUPLICATE since similar questions do NOT address this issue.  For example +the answer to the following question ("highest version selected by default") is NOT working

> [How could SBT choose highest version amongst dependencies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21442245/how-could-sbt-choose-highest-version-amongst-dependencies)

Comment: You can use [sbt-dependency-graph](https://github.com/jrudolph/sbt-dependency-graph) and see from where the `servlet-api` is included. You can do that by using `what-depends-on <organization> <module> <revision>`. Then you can exclude the transitive dependency. This is easier than excluding class from a specific jar (unless you don't care which jar, and you just want to take it from any jar). You can also check my answer to [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24363363/how-can-a-duplicate-class-be-excluded-from-sbt-assembly/24363781#24363781)

Comment: thx!  I will try this and likely follow-up with suggesting you make this an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [sbt-dependency-graph](https://github.com/jrudolph/sbt-dependency-graph) and see from where the `servlet-api` is included as a transitive dependency.

You can do that by using `what-depends-on <organization> <module> <revision>` command.

Knowing that you can exclude the transitive dependency.

This is easier than excluding class from a specific jar (unless you don't care which jar, and you just want to take it from any jar).

You can also check my answer to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24363363/how-can-a-duplicate-class-be-excluded-from-sbt-assembly/24363781#24363781) on how to write a custom `MergeStrategy`, which would know from which jar the class was comming.